# Filter and sort array of strings based on length?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, algorithm, sorting

for example,I have an array :

```
let arr=["a","bc","de","fgh","i","jkl"];
```

I want to :

1. select all strings which length >=2
2. and then sort it until the longest string at first, my desired result

   ["fgh","jk","bc","de"]

I tried:

```
let arr=["a","bc","de","fgh","i","jkl"];
let newArr=[];
for(let s of arr){
  if(s.length>=2){
    newArr.push(s);
  }
}
newArr.sort(function(a,b){
  return a.length<b.length;
});
//newArr should become ["fgh","jk","bc","de"] now
```

which has many lines of codes. Is there any algorithm look like that:

```
let arr=["a","bc","de","fgh","i","jkl"];
let newArr=[];
for(let s of arr){
  if(s.length>=2){
    //push it in to a suitable position
  }
}
//newArr should become ["fgh","jk","bc","de"] now
```

which newArr becomes the sorted array naturally? How should I write "push it in to suitable position"?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.filter()` and `.sort()`:

```js
let arr = ["a","bc","de","fgh","i","jkl"];

let result = arr.filter(({ length }) => (length >= 2))
                .sort((s1, s2) => s2.length - s1.length);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: That's incorrect. `Array#sort` expects a number out of the compare function.

Comment: @NisargShah Thanks for the input. I've corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) instead of manually filtering using a `for..of` loop.

Also, in case of [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), the comparison function expects numbers not boolean. So the returned value should be `b.length - a.length` instead of `a.length < b.length`.

Here's how I would write the code for it:

```js
let arr=["a","bc","de","fgh","i","jkl"];

var resultArray = arr.filter(function(t) {
  return t.length >= 2;
}).sort(function(a, b) {
  return b.length - a.length;
});

console.log(resultArray);

//newArr should become ["fgh","jk","bc","de"] now
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter()` to take the item whose length are grater or equal to 2:

```
.filter(i => i.length >= 2);
```

```js
let arr=["a","bc","de","fgh","i","jkl"];
let newArr = arr.filter(i => i.length >= 2).sort((a,b) => a.length < b.length);
console.log(newArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let arr = ["a","bc","de","fgh","i","jkl"];
```

let result = arr.filter(({ length }) => (length >= 2))
.sort((s1, s2) => s2.localeCompare(s1));

console.log(result);